# accumulate data from multiple csv from a blob storage to a hive table with MS Databricks or ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Can you please help me to find the best practice for the next task:
I have a blob storage shared with SAS. There are multiple csv in folder hierarchy  like root_folder -> leve1_folders -> level2_folders -> csv.
I need firstly read every csv that exists, save it as a hive table and then append new data to the hive table once new folders with csv (leve1_folders -> level2_folders -> csv) are uploaded.
The problem for me is to read last uploaded folders with csv only, the new folders name could be different, but the file name is the same always.

Comment: Can you please share your pipeline ? and maybe an example of your CSV file ?

Answer (score 0):

> append new data to the hive table once new folders with csv (leve1_folders -> level2_folders -> csv) are uploaded.

The above requirement can be fulfilled using Azure Data Factory using "Event Trigger".

> Data integration scenarios often require customers to trigger
> pipelines based on events happening in storage account, such as the
> arrival or deletion of a file in Azure Blob Storage account. Data
> Factory and Synapse pipelines natively integrate with Azure Event
> Grid, which lets you trigger pipelines on such events.

Limitation: The Storage Event Trigger currently supports only Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and General-purpose version 2 storage accounts.

Therefore, you need to convert the simple blob storage to `Hierarchical namespace` to make it ADLS account.

Refer: [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory)